# How to obtain a certain component using FEST

Tags: java, swing, automated-tests, fest

I have a problem with [FEST](http://code.google.com/p/fest/):

I have four `JtextField`s in a `JDialog`. How can I obtain a certain `JTextField` if I have four `JTextField`s, where attributes `name`, `text`, and `visibility` are undefined or null.

```
public class Form1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField tf2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField tf3 = new JTextField();
        JTextField tf4 = new JTextField();

        tf1.setPreferredSize(tf1.getPreferredSize());
        tf1.setText("");
        tf2.setPreferredSize(tf2.getPreferredSize());
        tf2.setText("");
        tf3.setPreferredSize(tf3.getPreferredSize());
        tf3.setText("");
        tf4.setPreferredSize(tf4.getPreferredSize());
        tf4.setText("");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        frame.add(tf1);
        frame.add(tf2);
        frame.add(tf3);
        frame.add(tf4);
        frame.setSize(300, 85);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: afair, you have to set the name property so that the component can be found

Comment: I haven't access to source code

Comment: hmm ... then you'll probably need to implement a custom Matcher (don't nail me on the name, it's been a while and writing this is from the top of my head ;-) You might consider asking your question on the FEST mailinglist, the lurkers there tend to respond rather quickly

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to run setName for all JComponent instances contained inside an object using Reflection. It will show stack overflow error if there are circular referencing inside the object.

```
public static void assignComponentNames(Object obj) {

    try {

        Method getComponentsMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod("getComponents", new Class[]{});

        if (null != getComponentsMethod){
            try {
                for (Component component : (Component[])(getComponentsMethod.invoke(obj))){
                    assignComponentNames(component);
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);

        String fieldName = field.getName(); //this is a different name, the reflection level name
        Object fieldValue = null;

        try {
            fieldValue = field.get(obj);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (null == fieldValue) {
            continue;
        }

        if (fieldValue instanceof JComponent) {

            String currentComponentNameForFieldValue = ((JComponent) fieldValue).getName();

            if (null == currentComponentNameForFieldValue){
                System.out.println("null component name");
                ((JComponent) fieldValue).setName(fieldName);  //this sets the name specially for JComponent
            }
        }
        else if(fieldValue instanceof Collection){

            for (Object subObject : ((Collection)fieldValue).toArray()) {

                assignComponentNames(subObject);
            }
        }

    }
}
```